# Simple as PhoneGap but faster apk file (better performance)?

Tags: android, html, cordova, phaser-framework

I've made a *very* simple game with phaser http://phaser.io/, max 5 animated sprites and 3 sounds. My game works perfectly on my computer but when I'm using PhoneGap 3.3.0 its lag on my Galaxy S3 (poor performance).

I like PhoneGap because you can easily upload a zip with an html5 game and download an apk (without additional work). Like even the users does not need to have anything else installed on their phone in order to play my game.

Something that provides better performance than PhoneGap but are still just as easy, and the user don't need to install anything extra? Don't want to learn real android programming. It should work with only the standard html5 (no extra framework you need to learn) although I plan to use the phaser.

It should also be possible to upload the apk file on Google play in the future.

Answer (score 5):

You can try to use [adobe's fastcanvas plugin](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/10) to replace the slow canvas of the android webview.

Or you can test [intel crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/#documentation/about/faq),  either directly or through [intel xdk](http://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/tools) and select build with crosswalk.

Crosswalk replaces the default webview with latest version of Chromium which should provide better performance on most devices.

Answer (score 1):

try CocoonJS, it works fine with phaser 2.0. You can download the CocoonJS launcher on the Play Store for trying and debugging your game and then get an APK from their website. Just check the [common issues](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/3980-common-phaser-cocoonjs-issues/).